# Android - PSPDFKit is there a way to know the current Zoom on the page?

Tags: android, zooming, pspdfkit

I am wondering if there is a way to know the zoom in the current document in order to navigate through documents but maintaining the zoom.

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PSPDFKit#getZoomScale`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/android/reference/com/pspdfkit/ui/PSPDFFragment.html#getZoomScale(int)) to get zoom scale for current page:

```
 fragment.getZoomScale(fragment.getPage());
```

Then, after loading new document, you can set required zoom scale with [`PSPDFFragment#zoomTo()`](https://pspdfkit.com/api/android/reference/com/pspdfkit/ui/PSPDFFragment.html#zoomTo(int,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20long)) like this:

```
 PSPDFDocument document = fragment.getDocument();
 fragment.zoomTo((int) document.getPageSize(pageToDisplay).width / 2,
                 (int) document.getPageSize(pageToDisplay).height / 2,
                 pageToDisplay, zoomScale, animationTime);
```

Where `animationTime` can be 0 to zoom immediately without animating.

Comment: Also quick note: We (the PSPDFKit team) can't actively follow all StackOverflow questions. We have a great custom support team that is immensely responsive and will answer your questions at https://pspdfkit.com/support/request

Comment: Thank you so much!